# Jquery Slide Toggle - How to change image on toggle?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to change the image inside `class="slide"` when its toggled.
There are several widgets like this so relevant widget image must be changed.

```
<div class="widget">
      <h3>Inhaltsverzeichnis</h3>
      <div class="widgetbox">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#"> Prozessbeschreibung</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Produkte & Dienstleistung </a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Beschaffen</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> Prozess-Steckbrief</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> Beschreibung</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> Mitgeltende Dokumente</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> Korrekturhinweise</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> Optimierungsvorschläge</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> Prozessübersicht</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="img/slideup.png" width="16" height="15" alt=""/</div>
    </div>
```

currently Js is

```
$(".slide").click(function(){
    $(this).prev().children().slideToggle("slow", function() { 

    });
});
```

now how can i change the img slideup.png to slidedown.png when the ul is hidden , the following works but it replaces all images from all widgets.

```
  if ($('div.widgetbox>ul').css("display")=="none") {  
      $(".slide>a>img").attr("src", "img/slidedown.png");
  }
  else{ 
      $(".slide>a>img").attr("src", "img/slideup.png");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give id for img tag
eg:

```
<img src="flower.png" id="image"/>
```

then

```
$(".slide").click(function(){
    $(this).prev().children().slideToggle("slow", function() { 
       $('#image').attr('src','sample.png');
    });});
```

Comment: result will be same, it will be repetation of codes to write new new id for every new box